Pyglet overlay/transparent style not transparent
When I run the program, the window (top right and bottom left) is supposed to be transparent but instead, it is black
Here is an image of the window:
Lilac window, with a grey line around the bottom and right edge, black, opaque squares on the bottom left and top right
There are no warning or errors in the console
Here is the code I used:
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import *

win = Window(width=650, height=370, style=Window.WINDOW_STYLE_OVERLAY, resizable=False)
screen = win.display.get_default_screen()
win.set_location((screen.width//2 - win.width//2) + 5, (screen.height//2 - win.height//2) + 5)

@win.event
def on_draw():
    win.clear()
    shadow = pyglet.shapes.Rectangle(x=10, y=0, width=win.width - 10, height=win.height - 10, color=(100, 100, 100, 100))
    shadow.draw()
    background = pyglet.shapes.Rectangle(x=0, y=10, width=win.width - 10, height=win.height - 10, color=(150, 100, 255))
    background.draw()

pyglet.app.run()

Extra context:
Python 3.12, latest pyglet version, Windows 11, and on PyCharm
I tried using python 3.8, the Window.WINDOW_STYLE_TRANSPARENT style, updating my drivers, changing the objects, and more, but nothing worked

Worked for me. I'm on Linux, python-3.12, pyglet 2.0.17 . Didn't use pycharm, started the script from the terminal

I think it might be my computer. I've been experiencing GPU issues lately.

Also tried VScode, didn't work

Update: I have tried updating other drivers than my GPU, and still nothing. I think it's just my hardware, so I shall try and use this code on a different device.
